# How to create a download counter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

OK so what I'm trying to do here is that I want a download counter which will count downloads in real time and output the value in real time without needing the user to clear their cache or refresh the page. Now I am able to achieve this using a little bit of  JavaScript (this is being used to update in real time) combined with MySQL and PHP. But the problem is that in order for me to get it to output the value in real-time, I mean when a user clicks on this "button" I have to create a span tag and contain it inside the anchor tag which contains the button/link I'm tracking.

To help you better understand, here are is my HTML and JavaScript.

```
<?php 

    foreach($files_array as $key=>$val)
    {
        echo '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="download.php?file='.urlencode($val).'"><span class="download-text">Download 
                </span></a><span class="download-count" title="Times Downloaded">'.(int)$file_downloads[$val].'</span>
                ';
    }

?>
```

And here is the JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/* This code is executed after the DOM has been completely loaded */

$('#download-button a').click(function(){

    var countSpan = $('.download-count',this);
    countSpan.text( parseInt(countSpan.text())+1);
}); });
```

I want to be able to not contain the span tag for the counter inside the  tag but outside it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Okay, but you need to relate each anchor with their respective download counter. Enclose both in list items, maybe?

Comment: thank you for answering and I just tried your solution but unfortunately it doesn't work if I enclose them both in separate <li> tags.

Comment: I meant adding both to the same li. Then you could do $(this).closest('li').find('.download-count')

Comment: @bfavaretto OK I understand now and I add this line '$(this).closest('li').find('.download-count')' to my JavaScript file right? Sorry I am a noob at this :/ 

Also, I want the counter to be unclick-able, meaning that only the button should be click-able and the counter value should either be just plain text or not click-able at all. Is this possible as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to poll how many global users have downloaded the item and update the frontend without refreshing the page you will either need to use sockets or setInterval():

Here's how you would do it with setInterval() and updating the numbers every 3 seconds (you don't want to do it too much or it will be a big load on your server):

```
<ul>
<?php 
    foreach($files_array as $key => $val) {
        echo "<li id=\"download-$key\">";
        echo '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="download.php?file=' . urlencode($val) . '"><span class="download-text">Download</span></a><span class="download-count" title="Times Downloaded">' . (int)$file_downloads[$val] . '</span>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
?>
</ul>

<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        $.getJSON('/download-count.php', function(e) {
            var i;
            for (i in e) {
                if (e.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    $('#download-' + i + ' .download-count').text(e[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    }, 3000); // ping every 3 seconds
</script>
```

You'll need a new file for your Ajax (in my example I called it `/download-count.php`) that will echo out the JSON for your numbers

```
echo json_encode($file_downloads);
```

This is obviously a simplistic example but hopefully it gets the point across.

UPDATE: The **download-count.php** file will need to look something like this:

```
<?php
    /**
     * You don't show how you populate $file_downloads in your question but
     * however you do it, do it the same way here
     */
    $file_downloads = foo();

    echo json_encode($file_downloads);

    die();
```

Comment: You're welcome! To explain the difference between my code and bfavaretto.  With bfavaretto's code. Person A goes to the site and it says 10 downloads. He clicks to download it and it will go up to 11.  Person B comes to the site, it now says 11 and he clicks to download it. Person B's browser shows 12 downloads but Person A's site still shows 11 and it will continue to show 11 until they refresh the page.  With my code Person B will click on the site and the count will go up to 12 and after Person A's site polls the Ajax their site will update to 12 as well! Everyone's site will stay in sync!

Comment: My solution is the only one that answers your question: "I want a download counter which will count downloads in real time and output the value in real time without needing the user to clear their cache or refresh the page." ;)

Comment: Ahan.. I understand what you just said I'll try that out now and mark yours as solved if it gives me the exact same results! Cheers mate :)

Comment: Can you also tell me what to include in my download-count.php file?

Answer (score 2):

What I suggested in the comments is something like this:

```php
<ul>
<?php 
    foreach($files_array as $key=>$val) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="download.php?file='.urlencode($val).'"><span class="download-text">Download</span></a><span class="download-count" title="Times Downloaded">'.(int)$file_downloads[$val].'</span>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* This code is executed after the DOM has been completely loaded */

    $('#download-button a').click(function(){
        var countSpan = $(this).closest('li').find('.download-count');
        countSpan.text( parseInt(countSpan.text(), 10) + 1);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH! chrislondon's solution was good as well but I tried out yours before trying his and it gave me the exact results I wanted :D

Comment: Thanks. But please note that my solution does not save the download count to the database.